# Regex matching: Case insensitive German words with spaces (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem where I want to match any number of German words inside [] braces, ignoring the case. The expression should only match spaces and words, nothing else i.e no punctuation marks or parenthesis
E.g :
The expression ['über das thema schreibt'] should be matched with ['Über', 'das', 'Thema', 'schreibt']
I have one list with items of the former order and another with the latter order, as long as the words are same, they both should match.

The code I tried with is -

```
regex = re.findall('[(a-zA-Z_äöüÄÖÜß\s+)]', str(term))
```

or

```
re.findall('[(\S\s+)]', str(term))
```

But they are not working. Kindly help me find a solution

Comment: You need to escape the square braces as those are special meaning in RegEx.  ```regex = re.findall('\[(a-zA-Z_äöüÄÖÜß\s+)\]', str(term))``` or ```re.findall('\[(\w\s+)\]', str(term))```

Comment: In regex anything between `[ ]` means match any of these chars, so maybe escape it

Comment: `[item for sublist in ast.literal_eval(str(term)) for item in sublist.split() if item.isalpha()]`, see [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/X5ZYAq).

Comment: Do youe want one single match from the regex or you want that the regex matches every single word?

Comment: Where do you want match spaces? Does this solves your question? https://regex101.com/r/GK4UOj/1

Comment: BTW, what type is term? Is it a list? Try `print(type(term))`. If it is, just use `[item for sublist in term for item in sublist.split() if item.isalpha()]`

Comment: I want one single match, whatever is between the [] braces, the whole expression, spaces can be anywhere, not a problem, the expression should match along with the order of the words

Comment: So ```re.findall('\[\'([\S\s]+?)\'\]', str(term))```

Comment: @SoumyaC Please check my comments and provide some feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest solution to it :

```
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    reg_a = re.findall('[(\w\s+)]', str(a).lower())
    reg_b = re.findall('[(\w\s+)]', str(b).lower())
    if reg_a == reg_b:
        return True
    else
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form using `\w+` works for finding words (needs Unicode flag for non-ascii chars), but since you want them to be within the square brackets (and quotes I assume) you'd need something a bit complex

```
\[(['\"])((\w+\s?)+)\1\]
```

`\[` and `\]` are used to match the square brackets
`['\"]` matches either quote and the `\1` makes sure the same quote is one the other end
`\w+` captures 1 word. The `\s?` is for an optional space.

The whole string is in the second group which you can split to get the list

```
import re
text = "['über das thema schreibt']"
regex = re.compile("\[(['\"])((\w+\s?)+)['\"]\]", flags=re.U) 
match = regex.match(text)
if match:
    print(match.group(2).split())
```

(slight edit as `\1` did not seem to work in the terminal for me)

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on comments to match each word. This simply ignores spaces, single quotes and square braces

```
import re
text = "['über das thema schreibt']"
re.findall("([a-zA-Z_äöüÄÖÜß]+)", str(text))

# ['über', 'das', 'thema', 'schreibt']
```

Comment: I am not trying to match "['über das thema schreibt']". I am trying to match "['über das thema schreibt']" with "['Über', 'das', 'Thema', 'schreibt']"

Comment: Still it is not considering the case, I want it to be case-sensitive. Is it possible using regular expressions? I am not very sure. Anyways thanks

Comment: Okay, I have updated it to use the pattern you used in your question so it will only match those, so ```re.findall("([a-zA-Z_äöüÄÖÜß]+)", str(term))``` but even that is  case insensitive for those characters as you included them in both upper and lower case.

Answer (score -2):

If you are solving case sensitivity issue, add the regex flaf `re.IGNORECASE`
like

```
re.findall('[(\S\s+)]', str(term),re.IGNORECASE)
```

You might need to consider converting them to unicode, if it did not help.

Comment: There is nothing in the `[(\S\s+)]` pattern that can be affected by `re.I` flag. The `[(\S\s+)]` pattern is a user error anyway.

Comment: That returns ```['[', "'", 'ü', 'b', 'e', 'r', ' ', 'd', 'a', 's', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', 'm', 'a', ' ', 's', 'c', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'i', 'b', 't', "'", ']']```